# Display array list elements in dropdown list in php

Tags: php, arrays, dropdown

For example, I have such array:

```
$someArray = Array (
    [stationList] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [stationName] => A.S.Peta Bypass
            [stationId] => -1 )
        [1] => Array (
            [stationName] => Aala
            [stationId] => -1 )
    )
)
```

Now U want to display the array elements(stationName) in a dropdown list in php, I used the below code:

```
<select id="txtLabourId">                                                                                                                          
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>

  <?php
    foreach($someArray as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $name['stationName'] ?>"><?php echo $name['stationName'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>                                                                                                              
</select>
```

But its giving the error:

```
Undefined index stationName on line 222
```

How to resolve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: check first with stationList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$someArray` array contains another array, so start your `foreach` loop  from the inner array like this

```
<?php
    foreach($someArray['stationList'] as $station) { 
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $station['stationId'] ?>"><?php echo $station['stationName'] ?></option>
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the inner array `stationList` into loop.

Your loop code should be like this:

```
foreach($someArray['stationList'] as $name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `stationList` to your `foreach`, not the wrapping array, so:

`foreach($someArray['stationList'] as $name) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

value
type 

";

echo "$val";

echo "".gettype($val)."";

}

?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).